# Sitecore powershell script - how to initialize custom scripts

Tags: powershell, sitecore, sitecore8

I used sitecore powershell last year to migration heaps of items.

I installed the latest one and I don't see "Initialization script" field under Console/All Users item.

I had used this field to intialize all my custom scripts like below so that I can access from PSE.

```
Execute-Script -Item (Get-Item -ID "{0B0E50B9-CD3C-4FE7-BB6D-D2A9AAEB7568}" -Path master:\)
```

Any help will be good.

Answer (score 0):

This was removed in SPE 3.1 due to the unpredictable nature.

https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/365

If you could post a new issue on what your custom script does, perhaps we can provide you with an alternate solution.